# MVC5 Identity Webapi Authentication

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, identity

I write a webapp with mvc5 and Identity for authentication. It's work fine.
Now I need to authenticate same client (ios app, windows phone app, and android app) with users that are registered. Think to use a specific webapi where user can register, modify, autheticate ours user. So when they are autenticated the use can access other webapi for get data. Is this correct procedure? How I can use Identity into webapi?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look into oAuth and JWT tokens. There is already a library built for this which works really well called Thinktecure. When you are authenticating from a mobile app you really want to go the route of stateless authentication and just pass a token with the necessary claims to identify the user. There is plenty of documentation on the site as well as a sample repo (below).

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/